# Handlebars.js returns empty markup

Tags: javascript, ajax, handlebars.js

I have a problem with rendering handlebars.js template. I'm doing AJAX request to server, and servers returns me data which contains 'dishes' array with objects.Dish object contains id,price,weight,description,and array of photos. Then i render it with handlebars,and its works properly, 'html' variable containts rendered markup.

```
    var data ;
    var modalDishInfo;
    var modalDishComments;
    var vitrina;

    function ajax(params){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/getDishByCategory',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: params,
            success: function (result){
       data = JSON.parse(result);

       vitrina = Handlebars.compile( $('#vitrina_template').html() );
       modalDishInfo = Handlebars.compile( $('#modalDishInfo').html() );
       var html = vitrina(data.dishes);
       console.log(html);
       $('.foodmenucontent').empty();
       $('.foodmenucontent').append(vitrina(data.dishes));
}

<script id="vitrina_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each this}}
<div class="col-lg-3 mealcard" >

            <a href="#" id="#dish{{ id }}" onclick="openModal(id)"><p class="text-center mealname">{{ dish_name }}</p></a>
            <div class="weightandprice">
                <div class="weightcontainer"><span class="mealweight pull-right">{{ dish_weight }} грамм</span></div>
                <div class="pricecontainer"><span class="mealprice pull-left">{{ dish_price }} руб.</span></div>
            </div>
            <button class="orderbutton center-block">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>
        </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

As you can see this code renders elements, which contains links with openModal() function.I have empty bootstrap modal window and want to render its content, according to clicked link.

```
function openModal(id){
        var foo = id.slice(-1);
        var modaldata = data.dishes;
        var modaldish = $.grep(modaldata, function (element) {
            return element.id == foo;
        });
        modaldish = modaldish[0];
        console.log(modaldish);
        var markup = modalDishInfo(modaldish);

        $('#modalDishInfo').empty();
        $('#modalDishInfo').append(markup);
        $('#modalDish').modal('show');
        $('.fotorama').fotorama();
    };
```

and template

```
<script id="modalDishInfo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<div class="modalcontainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-width="100%" data-      thumbwidth="80" data-thumbheight="45"
                 data-transition="crossfade" data-loop="true" data-keyboard="true" data-navposition="bottom"
                  data-fit="cover" data-ratio="1600/900">
                {{#each dish_photos}}
                    <img src="/uploads/gallery/{{ this.path }}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                {{/each}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p class="mealname">{{ dish_name}}</p>
            <pre>{{ dish_description }}</pre>
            <p>{{ dish_weight }}гр.</p>
            <p class="mealprice">{{ dish_price }}руб.</p><br>
            <button class="orderbutton ">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is second template(modalDishInfo) dont want to render, console.log returns 'markup' variable completely empty. I tried different combinations of block helpers, and expressions,but none of them working. Maybe im missing something important? Or need to use specific expressions, when passing single object to template?

Comment: send it as an array of one instead of a single object if the template is expecting an array. handlebars #each expects an array I believe and fails to process an object.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar Vitrina_template(that contains #each block) renders fine,as i pass an array to it. Problem is in second template.I pass a single object in it, but it doesn't want to render.

Comment: A jsfiddle or plunker might help, I am confused as to which data goes where from your question and when the handlebars gets compiled as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake that i did.My template id and container id(which is empty) are the same. So jquery selector returned me empty markup. I didn't notice that, because im using TWIG and my scripts was in {% verbatim %} tag to avoid TWIG errors, so i dont receive any errors or warning using duplicate ID's in code. Hope my answer is informative and can be helpful to someone.